# Python, how to remove paranticess

Tags: python

```
def coordinate():
    list = [[-180, -140], -220, -180]
    coordinates = []
    i = 0
    n = 1

    for x in range(list[0]):
        for y in range(list[n]):
            coordinates.append((x, y))

    return coordinates
```

Is there a way I can remove paranticess that appear in `list[0]`, `list[2]` because it appears that the for loop doesn't work this way because of the paranticess that occur when I do this.

Or any other way to make the for loop work?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to answer this, but after so many problems, it became too unclear what *exactly* your problem was. For example, you mean "parentheses", or square brackets? What are you trying to do with the code? What is it doing right now? I think you're topmost problem is in how you're misusing the range function. Google the range function and work through some examples, I think it'll really help.

Comment: @Back2Basics it ... could be a duplicate. But in this case just pressing 'delete' on the extra brackets would flatten the list. Also what is list[2]? I don't think list[2] is ever even accessed. Does OP mean list[0][1]?

Comment: @Back2Basics It's different from that question. Not all the elements are list.

Comment: Ahh I see.  I'll delete the duplicate answer then.

Comment: Don't name variables the same as a built-in type like `list` for example.

Answer (score 0):

to flaten a nested list, you can try this:

```
def flatten(container):                                                         
    for item in container:                                                      
        if isinstance(item, list):                                              
            for inner_item in flatten(item):                                     
                yield inner_item                                                 
        else:                                                                   
            yield item

>>> list(flatten([[-180, -140], -220, [-180]]))
[-180, -140, -220, -180]
>>> list(flatten([[-180, [-140]], -220, [-180]])) 
[-180, -140, -220, -180]
```

---

if all the elements are lists, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [[-180, -140], [-220], [-180]]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(l))
[-180, -140, -220, -180]
```